# Dynamic domain name prefix for Cognito User Pool domain

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I'm using Serverless Framework to create a Cognito user pool and based on the stage I'm deploying, I would like domain name prefixes like `myapp-dev`, `myapp-staging`, etc. The code I'm using in `serverless.yml` is like this:

```
  CognitoUserPoolDomain:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain
    Properties:
      Domain: myapp-${self:custom_stage}
      UserPoolId:
        Ref: CognitoUserPool
```

and

```
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
```

The `${self:custom_stage}` variable works for all other resources but not for the domain name as it's complaining about illegal characters. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the real name I was using instead of `myapp` was not accepted because it contained number characters. I've removed them and it works now.

It don't know why it wouldn't accept number characters, though, as the documentation says they can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpooldomain.html#cfn-cognito-userpooldomain-customdomainconfig), I would say your issue isn't with using the variable '${self:custom_stage}' but in that you are providing a string for the name without the [top-level-domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) accompaniment. Try adding the suffix to the name (e.g: .com).